# how to use submit form on codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to try no fresh my login after the user insert their username & password. I'm using on submit on form field like this to returning the same function without be refreshing. `onsubmit="return login();`

view

```
    <?php $this->load->view('header');?>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Store</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default login">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Sign In</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">       
                            <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" method="POST" onsubmit="return login();">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></span>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>     
                                 <div class="alert alert-danger text-center" style="display:none;" id="error">
                                    <p>Invalid username or password !!</p>
                                </div>    
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock frm-general"></span>Login</button>   
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="<?=base_url('assets/js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js');?>"></script>
        <script src="<?=base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');?>"></script>
        <script src="<?=base_url('assets/js/validator.min.js');?>"></script>
        <script src="<?=base_url('assets/js/view/login.js')?>"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Ajax

```
    $(function(){
    $('#login').submit(function(e){
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        URL_GET_ACCESS = BASE_URL+"Login_controller/login";
        $.ajax({
            url: URL_GET_ACCESS,
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
        }).done(function(ans){
            console.log(resp);
            if(ans === '0'){
                $('#error').show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
            }else if(ans === '1'){
                window.location.href='<?php echo base_url() ?>home/';
            }else{
                window.location.href='<?php echo base_url() ?>home/';
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi Diana, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is that the submission is being triggered and is taking you to the URL defined by your form action (in this case to itself).  To prevent this try using jQuery's `e.preventDefault();` as soon as you start your submit function.

Another solution I often use is not using a *submit* button but instead just a *span* (`<span id='iWillSubmit' class='iLookLikeAButton'>`) styled as a button and then attach the submit function to a `.on('click')` on that *span* element.